Error with cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback
lk_params = dict(level = 3, winSize = (15, 15), maxLevel = 2, criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))

next_point, status, error = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(gray_prev, gray_next, point, None, **lk_params)

How to solve this problem?
next_point, status, error = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(gray_prev, gray_next, point, None, **lk_params)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'calcOpticalFlowFarneback'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - calcOpticalFlowFarneback() missing required argument 'levels' (pos 5)
>  - calcOpticalFlowFarneback() missing required argument 'levels' (pos 5)


Welcome to Robotics, oliver. Your error states that you are missing the required argument levels - note the s on the end. When you define lk_params, you give a value for level - no s. What happens if you add an s to your lk_params entry?
